# Custom CheckBox of MultiChoiceItems in AlertDialog

Tags: android, checkbox, android-alertdialog, multichoiceitems

I seek how to custom a CheckBox in my MultiChoiceItems (i think the original on the phone is not good).

MultiChoiceItems is in a AlertDialog:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.builder(context);
builder.setTitle("string")
       .setMultiChoiceItems(item,selected,new DialogInterface.OnMultichoiceClickListener(){
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface,int item, boolean b){
              booleanArrayList.set(item,b);
           }
        });
builder.setPositiveButton("ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(DialogueInterface dialog,int which){
        //Mon code//
    }
 });
builder.setNegativeButton("retour",null)
       .create()
       .show();
```

This is working, i only have an issue with the skin of my checkbox and i search and not found solution,someone have ever do this?

Sorry for my English (I'm French ^^').

Thank you.

Edit//After search,I haven't find solution so i want to test with a setview; but i have an Exception with my code :

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.builder(context);
builder.setTitle("string");
builder.setPositiveButton("ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(DialogueInterface dialog,int which){
        //Mon code//
    }
 });
builder.setNegativeButton("retour",null)
```

And after that I add this : (this code is now ok for exception if someone need)

```
final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
LayoutInflater infl = alert.getLayoutInflater();
View dialog = infl.inflate(R.layout.mylistview,null);
alert.setView(dialog);
ListView lv=(ListView)dialog.findViewById(R.id.listviewcustom);
TextView tx; CheckBox cb;
LayoutInflater infl2 = alertDialog.getLayoutInflater();
vALlistview= new arrayList<View>(item.lenght);
vAAlistview= new ArrayAdaptater(context,R.id.listviewcustom);
for(ibcl=0;ibcl<item.lenght;ibcl++){
    View v = (infl2.inflate(R.layout.miccheckcustom,null);
    tx=(TextView)vALlistview.getChildAt(ibcl).findViewById(R.id.txtcustom);
    cb=(CheckBox)vALlistview.getChildAt(ibcl).findViewById(R.id.cbcustom);
    tx.setText(sAlTopicPoss.get(ibcl));
    cb.setChecked(false);
    vAAlistview.add(vALlistview.get(ibcl));
    }
vAAlistview.notifitDataSetChanged();
alert.show;
```

aspect of my xml (miccheckcustom):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout>
<TextView
    android:id="txtcustom"/>
<CheckBox
    android:id="cbcustom"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

But i have a LogCat tell me that :
"w/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception java.lang.ClassCastException"

//Edit2 : for the exception , my code is correct now , you can't add in a list an item directly , only with an arrayadaptater?//

//Edit2 : But now , my listview do nothing , i am only with a windows which have a title , 2 button but no listview in see ... I continue to search ...//

Sorry for my precision , my code is on an other pc ^^'

The first question is always in actuallity (just for knowledge) but if someone can help me for the exception, thank a lot ;)

Comment: why not use `setView()` and create your own custom layout?

Comment: Because the item "MultiChoiceItems" already exist and I only want change the skin of my CheckBox...
If i take a View , i don't know how to take an MultiChoiceItems (An other view with a Textview and a check box in a list view ?)
If nothing is possible, i would do that ...